# MS Access VBA | OnAction function with parameter doesn't work

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a commandbar with one button in it.

```
Private Sub RightClickNode(nodex As MSComctlLib.node)
    clicked = None
    Dim tv As TreeView
    Dim Bar As CommandBar
    Set Bar = CommandBars.Add(, msoBarPopup, False, True)
    Set tv = getTVSuper

    'EXPAND & COLLAPSE ALL RELATED BUTTON(S)
    Dim cmdExpand As CommandBarButton
    Set cmdExpand = Bar.Controls.Add(msoControlButton)

    With cmdExpand
        .OnAction = "=Expand('" & nodex.key & "')"
        .Caption = "Expand All"
        .Style = msoButtonAutomatic
        .FaceId = 706
    End With

    Bar.ShowPopup

    If Not clicked = toDelete Then
        tv.Nodes(nodex.key).EnsureVisible
        tv.Nodes(nodex.key).Selected = True
    Else
        tv.Nodes(1).EnsureVisible
    End If

    Set Bar = Nothing
    Set cmdExpand = Nothing
    Set tv = Nothing

End Sub

Public Function Expand(key)
    clicked = toExpand
    MsgBox "Hello"
End Function
```

The problem right now is that I have used this same code in another form within my project and I just took it and readjusted it. The code in the other is working fine, but in this one nothing happens.

ALSO, if I replace the name of the function in the OnAction property with a simple **MsgBox** :

```
With cmdExpand
    .OnAction = "=MsgBox('" & nodex.key & "')"
    .Caption = "Expand All"
    .Style = msoButtonAutomatic
    .FaceId = 706
End With
```

I received a well formed message box with the key-value of my nodex (Which is a node in a treeview by the way).

Do you have any idea of what is happening, I'm struggling with this for 2 hours now and it's something that I've already worked on in another form.

Comment: Try setting the parameter type to `String` in method. `Expand(key As String)`.

Comment: Yeah that wasn't doing anything when I tried it. But I realized that when I put this method in a new module, everything was working. So I did this. Unfortunately, I didn't find why it was doing this, might be a namespace related-error...